# Is Cloudflare enough to make Express.js app resistant against Bots?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, cloudflare

I'm using Cloudflare to do so. Is it necessary to add a Google Recaptcha to the login page?

Also, does Helmet interfere with Cloudflare's Bot Fight Mode?

I noticed when I refresh my every Express app page, in the browser console, there's a warning related to Cloudflare:

Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'. Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, ...

In front-end, execution of:

`<script src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/.../cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js" data-cf-settings="...`

faces some problem, I guess (the code was added by Cloudflare).

In Helmet's official docs, i found this link that evaluates the security of your site based on the response header:

`https://helmetjs.github.io/ https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/`
I used this code in my back-end:

```
`app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy(
        {
            directives:{
                scriptSrc:["'self'","https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com"]
            }
        }
  ))`
```

And csp-evaluator says it's all ok but:

cdnjs.cloudflare.com is known to host Angular libraries which allow to bypass this CSP

My back-end code has nothing to do with Angular.

How to solve it?